# In the "The Fly 2", why did teleporting cure his son?

Tags: the-fly

In Cronenburg's remake of "The Fly", a brilliant scientist invents a teleportation pod. He is scrambled with a fly that enters the pod. At first there is little change but after constant use his physiology is completely altered and he is turned into an 9 foot high "[Brundlefly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seth_Brundle)" hybrid

Before the major changes took place he impregnated a woman with his human/fly seed. The child grows up faster than normal in the sequel and during his puberty he begins to change but is cured by going into the pods with the villain of the movie.

The son in his human/fly state grabs the corrupt businessman, pulls him into the pod, it teleports them and he is kind of inside the bad guy's tail but is able to be taken out just by his girlfriend pulling him out.

My question is; **Why did going through the pod cure the son but not the father (who teleported plenty of times) and why wasn't the son permanently fused with the bad guy?**

Comment: There are too many questions here. Try splitting them up into several different ones

Comment: Whats hard to under stand im wondering how one use of the teloport made Brindles son human while only worsend brindle himself

Comment: I took off the star trek question the other is a follow up on another plot hole in the sequle because it was established in the first that two organisms would be fused together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-watching both movies it is stated in the end of the first movie in order to become human again seth would need to have a non-mutated human in one of the pods for the compute to discern between human and fly but he would either be fused with or the other human would be horribly mutated "you me and the baby, that all the human I could ever want. We would be the ultimate family" though I believe he wanted her ex-boyfriend, to cure himself, mutate her ex and live with her happily ever after.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure (as it's been a while since I've seen it), but when the son (Martin) goes through the telepod procedure with the "bad guy" (Bartok) the telepod computer was **programmed** to swap the mutant (fly) parts of his DNA with healthy DNA from Bartok. That is why he returned to human after the telepod procedure and Bartok turned into a mutant.

As to why they weren't fused together - I think Martin programmed the telepod computer to identify what was Martin and what was Bartok and keep that separate while only doing the gene-swapping stuff. But I don't know if that was mentioned in the film.

Comment: Its a long time since I've seen it too, but I was going to post an answer saying pretty much this. I also believe it's adequately explained in the movie, which I now want to go and re-watch.

Comment: @Binary Worrier... you could stream it on Solarmovie.ag